# Hibernate Criteria Question

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Suppose that I have two Hibernate POJOs: Customer and Order. The Order table has three relevant columns: customerId, totalItemsSold, and totalCost. The Customer table has columns: customerId, firstName, lastName, and city.

I've mapped a many-to-one between the Order and Customer tables. My Order POJO contains a Customer object. I want to do the following Criteria query:

```
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Order.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("customer.city", "Chicago"));
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(crit);
```

This always throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: customer.city of: Order
```

How can I use Criteria to search for Orders based on the customer's city? My Order pojo does contain a Customer object named "Customer" with appropriate getter and setters.....

**Edit (Order/Customer Class) as requested:**

```
public class Customer {
     private Integer customerId;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String city;

     public Integer getCustomerId() { return customerId; }
     public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) { this.customerId = customerId; }
     public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
     public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
     public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
     public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
     public String getCity() { return city; }
     public void setCity(String city) { this.city = city; }
}

public class Order { 
     private Customer customer;
     private Integer totalItemsSold;
     private Integer totalCost;

     public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
     public void setCustomer(Customer customer) { this.customer = customer; }
     public Integer getTotalItemsSold() { return totalItemsSold; }
     public void setTotalItemsSold(Integer totalItemsSold) { this.totalItemsSold = totalItemsSold; }
     public Integer getTotalCost() { return totalCost; }
     public void setTotalCost(Integer totalCost) { this.totalCost = totalCost; }
}
```

Here is the Order class's hbm mapping (which contains the mapping between Customer and Order):

```
<many-to-one name="customer" class="Customer" column="customerId" />
```

Comment: can you post your Order and Customer code?

Comment: @Jeff - they are added to my post

Comment: @David - Please also always post the complete Hibernate mapping of the relevant entities, beside the queries, exception messages, and POJO code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've posted seems fine.  Maybe there is an error in your hbm file?

Without seeing the full hbm, I'd be tempted to explicitly tell your detached criteria about the customer relationship:

```
crit.createAlias("customer", "customer");
```

Comment: Interesting....Adding the alias did let me query based on the customer object, but now the results are duplicated. For example, Bob makes an order on Jan 1, Feb 1, and Mar 1. I get three copies of the Jan 1 order, three copies of the Feb 1, and three copies of March 1st order. Very Strange. Any ideas?

Comment: Adding crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) fixed the duplication problem.

Comment: Sounds like a cartesian product issue.  This is not a Hibernate issue in that case, but an issue with your query logic.  It's tough to say exactly where the problem might be because your entities don't seem to match up with your description (no order dates) and your hbm isn't posted (which would show other many-to-one relationships and fetch types).  Eager fetching of multiple collection types is often the duplicate rows culprit.

Comment: IIRC, DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY just masks your problem.  Because it's a result transformer, the duplicate rows are still returned from the DB, but then Hibernate filters them out.  This is a problem for two reasons: it indicates that your query is not correct, and it puts unnecessary load on the DB for the incorrect joins.  This can lead to degraded performance as those tables grow

Comment: I think that I have a guess about what is the problem. When we used crit.createAlias("customer", "customer"), hibernate might be doing a full join (similar to select * from customer, order). How would I assign a restriction on createAlias? Sort of like crit.mustEqual("customerId", "customerId") to force the customerId values to be equal (like select * from customer inner join order on customer.customerId = order.customerId)?

Comment: Use the overloaded createAlias method that takes a joinType.  Check the CriteriaSpecification object for joinType constants.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just searching by customerId then what you have :

```
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Order.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("customer.customerId", 12));
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(crit);
```

might work. Otherwise Jeff and others mentioned above, you have to have the join with Customer table like  mentioned

```
crit.createAlias("customer", "customer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Customer instance variable in your Order class called customer or customerId?

Comment: The customer object is named Customer, but the primary key is named customerId.